# How to give parameter as input in PL/SQL CURSOR?

Tags: input, plsql, parameters, cursor

I am trying to execute the below code. 
I am giving v_Model_UserName as input. And i am using it in the select statement. But the parameter is not getting inputed in the select statement.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    v_Model_UserName VARCHAR2(30) := UPPER('&Model_UserName');
    v_role VARCHAR2(3000);
    CURSOR v_role1 is
    SELECT granted_role from dba_role_privs where grantee = ('v_Model_UserName') ;
    BEGIN
    OPEN v_role1;
    LOOP
    FETCH v_role1 INTO v_role;
    EXIT WHEN v_role1%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_role);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE v_role1;
    END;
    /
```

Eg. If i give &Mode UserName as HR, It is getting assigned to the variable  as v_Model_UserName = HR.

But in the cursor select statement it is still as

```
"SELECT granted_role from dba_role_privs where grantee =
```

('v_Model_UserName');"

I wanted it to be :

```
"SELECT granted_role from dba_role_privs where grantee = 'HR';"
```

I have also tried to give

```
  SELECT granted_role from dba_role_privs where grantee = v_Model_UserName;
```

Still the HR value is not getting assigned here.

Comment: My advice is to lay out code neatly and clearly. It will be easier to understand, maintain, and debug. For example, `declare`, `begin` and `end` belong at the same level, and the contents of the loop should be one indent to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made cursor syntax error.
Below code works.

```
DECLARE
    v_Model_UserName VARCHAR2(30) := UPPER('&Model_UserName');
    v_role VARCHAR2(3000);
    CURSOR v_role1 (var01  Varchar2 )is
    SELECT granted_role from dba_role_privs where grantee = var01;
    BEGIN
    OPEN v_role1 (v_Model_UserName);
    LOOP
    FETCH v_role1 INTO v_role;
    EXIT WHEN v_role1%NOTFOUND;
      dbms_output.put_line(v_role);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE v_role1;
    END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't quote the variable name, as that makes it just a string of text 'v_Model_UserName':

```
SELECT granted_role from dba_role_privs where grantee = v_Model_UserName;
```

(I also removed the redundant parentheses.  They did no harm, but added no value).

Comment: tried this but still the input is not getting added here. It is still the same.

Comment: @Kiruthika you need to update your question with the code you are now running then, because I have given the correct fix based on what your question currently says!